# Why can't I Tame My Ocelot in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am feeding it raw cod AND raw salmon and it will not tame! I have tried 4 different ocelots and none of them will tame. When I hold the fish the ocelot says "feed" not "tame" and they are still ocelots, not cats...

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ocelot#Taming

Answer (score 0):

The ocelot has to first be in taming mode.
To make the ocelot enter taming mode you must be between 6-10 blocks away and holding raw salmon or cod. If you turn or move quickly it will exit taming mode for 15 seconds. Then you feed the ocelot.
If the ocelot has grey/gray particles it didn’t work and you will have to try again. Once you have tamed it it will have heart particles.

[Ocelot taming](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot#Taming)